# Group Theory Problem From Topics In Algebra Written by I N Herstein

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that whenever $Ha\neq Hb$ then $aH\neq bH.$ 
 Prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is subset of $H$ for all $g\in G$.

We have to prove $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$; *i.e.*, $gHg^{-1} \setminus H = \emptyset$.  Suppose $gHg^{-1} \setminus H \neq \emptyset.$  Then $\exists x \in gHg^{-1}$ but $x \notin H$.  We have $xg=gh$ for all $g$.  We also have:

> > If $a, b \in G, xa=ah_1, xb= bh_2$.

Next I can not proceed.

Comment: Yes Just Subset of The Subgroup H

Comment: Also did you really mean subset of H? [that would make $H$ normal, no?]

Comment: Okay, I understand it now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We first show that $aH=Ha$ for every $a \in G$. First, let $x\in aH$. Then $aH=xH$, which gives, by hypothesis of the exercise, the equation $Ha=Hx$. However, $x$ is an element of $Hx$ so then $x$ is an element of $Ha$ [as $Ha=Hx$]. So then from this we conclude the following: for each element $x\in aH$, the element $x$ is also in $Ha$, or equivalently, $aH \subseteq Ha$. As the equations $|Ha|$ $=|H|$ $=|aH|$ hold however, it follows that $aH$ and $Ha$ must in fact be the same set for every $a \in G$. So indeed, $$aH=Ha \quad \forall a \in G.$$

So from this we get [left-multiplying both sides of the above by $a^{-1}$]:
$$H = a^{-1}Ha \quad \forall a \in G,$$ which is the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 9 on p.47.
I solved this problem as follows:

> Let $g$ be an arbitrary element of $G$.
> Let $h$ be an arbitrary element of $H$.
> Let $a:=gh$.
> Let $b:=g$.
> Then $a=bh$.
> So, $aH=bH$.
> Then, $Ha=Hb$ by the assumption of Problem 9.
> So, $Hgh=Hg$.
> So, $Hghg^{-1}=Hgg^{-1}=H$.
> So, $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: RE your second-to-last line: You cannot assume a priori that $gh =h'g$ for some $h'\in H$ i.e., that $gH \subseteq Hg$ however. [In fact that is indeed true, but you need to show this is so!]